# How can you use SailsJs as a library?

Tags: javascript, sails.js

I'm trying to use sailsjs as a library for a project with specific node files that use models.

```
# /testfile.js
process.chdir(__dirname);

// Ensure a "sails" can be located:
(function() {
    var sails;
    try {
        sails = require('sails');
    } catch (e) {
        console.error('To run an app using `node app.js`, you usually need to have a version of `sails` installed in the same directory as your app.');
        console.error('To do that, run `npm install sails`');
        console.error('');
        console.error('Alternatively, if you have sails installed globally (i.e. you did `npm install -g sails`), you can use `sails lift`.');
        console.error('When you run `sails lift`, your app will still use a local `./node_modules/sails` dependency if it exists,');
        console.error('but if it doesn\'t, the app will run with the global sails instead!');
        return;
    }

    // Try to get `rc` dependency
    var rc;
    try {
        rc = require('rc');
    } catch (e0) {
        try {
            rc = require('sails/node_modules/rc');
        } catch (e1) {
            console.error('Could not find dependency: `rc`.');
            console.error('Your `.sailsrc` file(s) will be ignored.');
            console.error('To resolve this, run:');
            console.error('npm install rc --save');
            rc = function () { return {}; };
        }
    }


    // Start server
    sails.lift(rc('sails'));

    var req = require('sails/lib/router/req');
    var res = require('sails/lib/router/res');

    while(!sails.isLifted)
    {


    }

    console.log(sails);
    sails.models.user.find({where: {email: 'test@test.com'}}, function (err, result) {
        if(err) return res().send('Not found');
        return res().send('Found')
    });

})();
```

I don't want a server running but I want all the configuration options to be used. I've edited the globals.js file to expose models.

```
models: true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bit of wrestling, found that sails takes a bit to 'lift'. I'm using a timeout at the moment but will probably clean that bit up after I get more working.